# Stop Image in Canvas at Canvas Borders

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, controls

##### I am trying to write a little Game with JS and discovered Canvas.

I have a picture drawn on the Canvas which is **bigger** than the Canvas and on WASD it should move
But it should stop when it hits the Border of the Canvas.
On the top and Left Side this works but I have no Idea how I can implement Logic to stop at the right or bottom.

### Here is my Js and Html:

#### JavaScript:

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

const overlay = document.querySelector('.overlay');

// canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
// canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

const border = new Image();
border.src = './stoneBorder.png'

let borderX = 24;
let borderY = 32;
const borderPixelSize = 8;
const borderSpeed = 2;
const keys = [];


border.onload = () => {
    ctx.drawImage(border, - borderX * borderPixelSize, - borderY * borderPixelSize);

    overlay.style.backgroundImage = "url('biggerCanvasWithoutTransparentOverlay.png')"
}

document.addEventListener('keydown', (ev) => {

    keys[ev.keyCode] = true;

    if (keys[87] || keys[38]) up(); // W | ArrowUp
    if (keys[65] || keys[37]) left();// A | ArrowLeft
    if (keys[83] || keys[40]) down();// S | ArrowDown
    if (keys[68] || keys[39]) right();// D | ArrowRight
})

document.addEventListener('keyup', (ev) => {
    keys[ev.keyCode] = false;
});

function up() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width,canvas.height);
    if (borderY > borderSpeed % borderPixelSize) borderY -= borderSpeed;
    ctx.drawImage(border, - borderX * borderPixelSize, - borderY * borderPixelSize);
}

function left() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width,canvas.height);
    if (borderX >= borderSpeed) borderX -= borderSpeed;
    ctx.drawImage(border, - borderX * borderPixelSize, - borderY * borderPixelSize);
}

function down() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    borderY += borderSpeed;
    ctx.drawImage(border, -borderX * borderPixelSize, -borderY * borderPixelSize);
}

function right() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width,canvas.height);
    borderX += borderSpeed;
    ctx.drawImage(border, - borderX * borderPixelSize, - borderY * borderPixelSize);
}
```

#### HTML:

```html
// to fit in the background Image
<canvas width="1280" height="752"></canvas>
```